# Later.js - Event not triggering on scheduled time

Tags: javascript, laterjs

I'm using Later.js, and trying to use `setInterval` to a schedule. I get very strange behaviour, if I set the schedule just a little bit forward in time, it works. But when I use the time i really would like to have, nothing happens at those time periods. I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
"use strict";
var settings = require('./settings');
var later = require('later');
later.date.localTime();

console.log("ProjectTwo started.");

createEvents();

function createEvents() {
    settings.eventSettings.forEach(function(setting) {
        if (typeof setting.schedule === 'object' ) {
            var schedule = { schedules: [ setting.schedule ] };
            later.setInterval(function() { switchLights(setting) } , schedule);
            console.log(s.next(2));
        }
    });
}

function switchLights(setting) {
    console.log((new Date()).toLocaleString() + " " + setting.name);
}

//switchLights(settings.eventSettings[0]);
```

and the settings:

```
"use strict";

var settings = {
    eventSettings: [
        {
            id: 1,
            schedule: { h: [2], m: [0]},
            //schedule: { h: [16], m: [16]},
            name: "One",
        }, 
        {
            id: 2,
            schedule: { h: [6], m: [0]},
            //schedule: { h: [16], m: [9]},
            condition: "if_dark",
            name: "Two",
        }, 
        {
            id: 3,
            schedule: { h: [8], m: [30]},
            //schedule: { h: [16], m: [10]},
            name: "Three",
        } 
    ]
};

module.exports = settings;
```

If I switch the commented out `schedule` rows it works! But the when I use the not commented out rows (the ones I really want) nothing happens at 2:00 AM, 6:00 AM and 8:30 AM.

Looking at the console.log(s.next(2)) printouts, they are always correct. But nothing happens at those times, if they are a further bit into the future.

### EDIT

I have done furher tests now, and as it turns out, it was a problem with how I run the app. I run it with NOHUP on a Raspberry Pi (which has worked in other cases). For some reason that does not work. I then tried using [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to run the same code. That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`later.setInterval` takes a function to execute at the mentioned time provided inside your schedule:{},in your case switchLights(setting) would be executed three times at the specified time i.e 02:00,06:00,08:30 every day

I'd suggest you to mention schedule object in seconds or the nearest time and you'll see all the three schedules executing your defined function at the given time
(for testing)

```
var later = require('later');
later.date.localTime();

var settings = {
    eventSettings: [
        {
           id: 1,
           schedule: { s: [10]},
           //schedule: { h: [13], m: [13]},//mention  your closest time
           name: "One"
        },
       {
           id: 2,
           schedule: { s: [26]},
           //schedule: { h: [13], m: [14]},
           //condition: "if_dark",
           name: "Two"
       },
       {
           id: 3,
           schedule: { s: [48]},
           //schedule: { h: [13], m: [15]},
           name: "Three"
       }
      ]
};
console.log("ProjectTwo started.");
createEvents();

function createEvents() {
 settings.eventSettings.forEach(function(setting)
 {
 if (typeof setting.schedule === 'object' ) 
  {
        var schedule = { schedules: [ setting.schedule ] };
        later.setInterval(function() { switchLights(setting) } ,schedule)
  }
 });
 }

function switchLights(setting)
{
console.log((new Date()).toLocaleString() + " " + setting.name);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, with the commented rows (//schedule: { h: [13], m: [13]}) when the time was i.e. 13:10. Then it executes fine. It seems like when the time is longer into the future, it never triggers for some reason....

Comment: Not sure whether i understood your question **"I get very strange behaviour, if I set the schedule just a little bit forward in time, it works. But when I use the time i really would like to have, nothing happens at those time periods."** But your code worked perfectly for me ,Check this out [link1](http://imgur.com/WEPIWsv)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. I have done furher tests now, and as it turns out, it was a problem with how I run the app. I run it with NOHUP on a Raspberry Pi (which has worked in other cases). For some reason that does not work. I then tried using pm2 to run the same code. That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with laterjs.
The reason is some how it calculates the time periods not correctly.
To fix that, just need to add `later.date.localTime()` before your code.